# How to Initialize an empty R list with a vector?

Tags: r, list, initialization, lapply

How can I create a list which is initialised with a vector of a given length?

For example
`empty_list <- vector("list", 10)` creates an empty list with a length of 10 and can be all initialised with a value using `empty_list[1:10] <- 25` but it's not possible to set their value to a vector and the following code results in error: `empty_list[1:10] <- vector("numeric", 15)`.

Here is the error produced: **Warning message:
In empty_list[1:10] <- vector("numeric", 15) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length**

I can do this using for loop:

`empty_list <- vector("list", 10)`

`for (i in 1:11) { empty_list [[i]] <- vector("numeric", 15) }`

But I am wondering if there is a better way than using **for loop** available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way to solve your problem:

```
empty_list = rep_len(list(numeric(15)), 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about just using `lapply` or `replicate()`?

```
empty_list <-lapply(1:10, \(i) vector("numeric",15))
```

or

```
empty_list <- replicate(10, vector("numeric", 15),simplify = F)
```

If `empty_list` has already been created and has names, like this:

```
empty_list <- vector("list", 10)
names(empty_list) <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

then these names will be retained if you do this:

```
empty_list <-lapply(empty_list, \(i) vector("numeric",15))
```

Output:

```
$A
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$B
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$C
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$D
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$E
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$F
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$G
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$H
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$I
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$J
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Worked! What if each element of the list has a name?

Comment: Use `names(empty_list) <- c("names1", "name2", ... , "name10)` to rename it

Comment: you can set the names as @jpsmith indicates  Or, if `empty_list` already has names (i.e. when empty), you can retain them by passing `empty_list` to the `lapply()` example in my solution.  See the update